# Keyerror showing while using python pandas drop function

Tags: python

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
df = pd.read_csv("Covid-19 Global Data.csv")

df.head(3)

      Date_reported   Country_code    Country        WHO_region     New_cases                New_deaths
     0     03-01-20          AF       Afghanistan      EMRO           0                               0                                   
     1     04-01-20          AF       Afghanistan      EMRO           0                               0                                   
     2     05-01-20          AF       Afghanistan      EMRO           0                               0                                  

df.drop(["Country"],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Showing keyerror everytime. The dataframe is constructed perfectly but `KeyError` is popping up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error could be due to the additional whitespace in the column name. Perhaps try adding a whitespace and dropping it:

```
df.drop(["Country "],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Or

```
df.drop([" Country"],axis=1,inplace=True)
# df.drop([" Country "],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

One better way would be strip extra whitespace from the column names with the following:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip()
df.drop(["Country"],axis=1,inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you have already dropped the `Country` column.

Worked well for me.

Restart the karnel and try to run it again.

Comment: No i didn't drop any of the columns of the data frame. The code is not working for any of the columns even after restarting the kernel

Comment: Then check the whitespace of the Country name. Like ' Country' or 'Country '

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
print(df.columns)
```

to see real names of your columns. You obtained something as

> ```
> Index(['Date_reported', 'Country_code', 'Country', 'WHO_region', 'New_cases',
>        'New_deaths'],
>       dtype='object')
> ```